# json serialize c++

Tags: c++, json

I have this C++ code, and am having trouble json serializing it.

```
 string uInput;
 string const& retInput;
 while(!std::cin.eof()) {
   getline(cin, uInput);
   JSONExample source; //JSON enabled class from jsonserialize.h
   source.text = uInput;
   //create JSON from producer
   std::string json = JSON::producer<JSONExample>::convert(source); //string -> returns {"JSONExample":{"text":"hi"}}
   //then create new instance from a consumer...
   JSONExample sink = JSON::consumer<JSONExample>::convert(json);
   //retInput = serialize(sink);
   // Json::FastWriter fastWriter;
   // retInput = fastWriter.write(uInput);
   retInput = static_cast<string const&>(uInput);
   pubnub::futres fr_2 = pb_2.publish(chan, retInput);
   cout << "user input as json which should be published is " << retInput<< std::endl;
```

Comment: Could you try to change the while-loop into `while (getline(cin, uInput))` to make sure you don't loop once to much ?  And show us the input you provide on `cin` ?

Comment: And does `string const& retInput;` compile without providig an intialiszation ??

Comment: it does not compile without providing an initialization, changed that to regular std::string. 

The input provided on cin is like "hi" "1 more week left of school" etc

Comment: can you provide the _exact_ output you get with the last line in your code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 while(!cin.eof()) {
   getline(cin, uInput);
   newInput = "\"\\\""; 
   newInput += uInput;
   newInput += "\\\"\"";
```

Instead of typing in the message like "\"hi\"", this code takes "hi" and does it.

Answer (score 1):

If the change you described made the "Invalid JSON" disappear, then a "more correct" solution would be, AFAICT, to change the `publish()` line to:

```
pubnub::futres fr_2 = pb_2.publish(chan, json);
```

Because `json` already has JSON serialized data. Of course, if that JSON is what you want to publish.